# Unable to publish Rshiny application using Rstudio connect

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker-studio, rstudio-connect

From AWS sagemaker Rstudio, I am trying to publish a simple shiny web application using Rstudio connect. 'rsonnect' package installed on rstudio IDE is '0.8.29'. Added the rstudio connect certificate and able to login to rstudio connect server via the rstudio console using the below commands.

```
rsconnect::addconnectServer(url="rstudio connect url", certificate="rstudio connect .pem certificate path", 'rconnect') 

rsconnect::connectuser('username', 'rconnect')
```

It redirected to the rstudio connect login page, login is successful.but if i try to publish the application, I get the below error.

I followed the below article, and appended the rstudio connect certificate with the cacert.pem still i see the same error.

Error message: could not deploy application 'r shiny application'. an error occurred while executing method

Rstudio article: https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/115006524187-Publishing-to-an-RStudio-Connect-Server-with-a-Self-Signed-or-Untrusted-SSL-Certificate

I am able to run the application, i get this error only if i try to publish.
I am new to R programming and Rstudio connect. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Contact support at Posit would be an option?